# RSelenium - Not able to perform operations after hanging on a website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I am webscraping using RSelenium. After hanging on a website for some minutes, I get the following error message:

> "_Error in .Call(R_curl_fetch_memory, enc2utf8(url), handle, nonblocking) :
> reached elapsed time limit"

It always hang during the following operation:

```
remDr$navigate(URL)
```

After applying an error handler, I want to close the current window and start a new webdriver. Unfortunately, I can't connect to the current window to perform any operations, so I also can't find a way to close the current window because the operation was aborted because of an application callback. I suspect that the connection is reset.

Since the website I am scraping hangs quite often, after a while tens of windows are open, which slows down everything.

I don't know if it is relevant, but the setting for the webdriver is as follows:

```
 prefs = list("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images" = 2L, "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
               "excludeSwitches","disable-popup-blocking"=TRUE) 
  cprof <- list(chromeOptions = list(prefs = prefs, w3c=FALSE))
  remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = 'chrome', extraCapabilities = cprof, port=4444L)
```

Every help is appreciated.

I have attempted the following ways to close the window, but nothing helps:

- remDr$close()
- remDr$quit()
- remDr$closeWindow()
- remDr$closeall()

I get a message that no connection could be made to server.

Comment: Can you share the website you are trying to scrape?

Comment: I scrape multiple websites and it hangd in almost all of them, so it is not specific to the website. I forgot to mention that it hangs in this operation: remDr$navigate(URL). I will edit my question

Comment: Sure, but without the site we are not able to replicate the issue / perhaps give you a better solution

Comment: I scrape sport websites such as https://www.livescore.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the network section, you will see that the site fetches data from their API. You can do the same as such:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

df <- "https://prod-public-api.livescore.com/v1/api/app/date/soccer/20240302/1?countryCode=NO&locale=en&MD=1" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  pluck("Stages") %>% 
  unnest(Events) %>% 
  unnest(c(T1, T2), names_sep = "_")

# A tibble: 1,291 × 50
   Sid   Snm        Scd   badgeUrl firstColor Cnm   Csnm  Ccd   CompId CompN CompD CompST   Scu Eid   Pids$`12` Media$`12`
   <chr> <chr>      <chr> <chr>    <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <int> <chr> <chr>     <list>    
 1 14414 Premier L… prem… 2023-pr… 3F1152     Engl… Engl… engl… 65     Prem… Engl… Engla…     0 9682… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 2 14414 Premier L… prem… 2023-pr… 3F1152     Engl… Engl… engl… 65     Prem… Engl… Engla…     0 9682… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 3 14414 Premier L… prem… 2023-pr… 3F1152     Engl… Engl… engl… 65     Prem… Engl… Engla…     0 9682… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 4 14414 Premier L… prem… 2023-pr… 3F1152     Engl… Engl… engl… 65     Prem… Engl… Engla…     0 9682… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 5 14414 Premier L… prem… 2023-pr… 3F1152     Engl… Engl… engl… 65     Prem… Engl… Engla…     0 9682… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 6 14414 Premier L… prem… 2023-pr… 3F1152     Engl… Engl… engl… 65     Prem… Engl… Engla…     0 9682… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 7 14414 Premier L… prem… 2023-pr… 3F1152     Engl… Engl… engl… 65     Prem… Engl… Engla…     0 9682… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 8 14500 LaLiga     lali… 2023-sp… 8B0D11     Spain Spain spain 75     LaLi… Spain Spain      0 9765… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
 9 14500 LaLiga     lali… 2023-sp… 8B0D11     Spain Spain spain 75     LaLi… Spain Spain      0 9765… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
10 14500 LaLiga     lali… 2023-sp… 8B0D11     Spain Spain spain 75     LaLi… Spain Spain      0 9765… SBTE_1_3… <df>      
# ℹ 1,281 more rows
# ℹ 38 more variables: Pids$`29` <chr>, $`8` <chr>, Media$`29` <list>, $`32` <list>, T1_Nm <chr>, T1_ID <chr>,
#   T1_Img <chr>, T1_NewsTag <chr>, T1_Abr <chr>, T2_Nm <chr>, T2_ID <chr>, T2_Img <chr>, T2_NewsTag <chr>, T2_Abr <chr>,
#   Eps <chr>, Esid <int>, Epr <int>, Ecov <int>, ErnInf <chr>, Et <int>, Esd <dbl>, EO <int>, EOX <int>, LS6 <int>,
#   Spid <int>, Pid <int>, Tr1 <chr>, Tr2 <chr>, Tr1OR <chr>, Tr2OR <chr>, Trh1 <chr>, Trh2 <chr>, Ewt <int>,
#   seriesInfo <df[,4]>, Awt <int>, Trp1 <chr>, Trp2 <chr>, secondColor <chr>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: HoelR, thank you for your response.

I am aware of the API for livescore.com. However, this is not where my issue is about. The odd thing is that I visually see that the browser navigates to the relevant website, but somehow it does not fully perform the navigation, since it does not perform the next part of the code. And since it the operation gets aborted, it will also not perform any operations on the webdriver after that. Let's say that 99 out of the 100 times, it does succesfully navigate, and in one of the cases, it hangs.